# $C(\mathbf{S}^1)\rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbf{Z}_2$ in Künneth formula

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, topological-k-theory

Let $\alpha$ be the action of $\mathbf{Z}_2$ on $\mathbf{S}^1$ (the circle seen in the complex plane) which sends $z$ to $\bar{z}$. Consider the crossed product $A = C(\mathbf{S}^1)\rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbf{Z}_2$. Let $B$ be another C*-algebar such that $K_*(B)$ is torsion-free. Does the following hold?:
\begin{align}
K_0(A\otimes B) \simeq (K_0(A)\otimes K_0(B))\oplus(K_1(A)\otimes K_1(B))\\
K_1(A\otimes B) \simeq (K_0(A)\otimes K_1(B))\oplus(K_1(A)\otimes K_0(B))
\end{align}
Said another way: Can I use the Künneth formula to compute $K_*(A\otimes B)$ given the $A$ described above?

Comment: I believe it's not so hard to show that the K-functor satisfies the properties of the acyclic model theorem, that is, you can show that it satisfies the conditions for the algebraic kunneth form. Maybe you can look in Switzer's Algebraic Topology, but I really can't recall if that's proved, would be in chapter 13.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! I know that the Kunneth formal holds for this K-theory, cf. Blackadar - K-theory for operator algebras thm. 23.1.3. However, it only holds for certain C*-algebras A, hence I would like to know whether the A I wrote above applies.

Comment: I believe $A$ should be separable and Type I (see Section 7.5 of Dana Williams' book on Crossed products). Then see Theorem 7.3.1 here: https://www.impan.pl/swiat-matematyki/notatki-z-wyklado~/k_theory.pdf

Comment: Thanks Prahlad! I know about the reference you gave. Is there a simple way to determine whether $A$ is seperable and of type I? Of course the action of $\mathbf{Z}_2$ on $\mathbf{S}^1$ has fixed points.

Comment: Hi. You have to check that $A$ lies in the bootstrap class. If $C$ is a separable $C^*$-algebra, $\alpha$ is an action on $C$ by a finite group $G$, then is the crossed product $C\rtimes_\alpha G$ separable. Here $S^1$ as a compact Hausdorff space is metrizable, so $C(S^1)$ is separable. Therefore your crossed product is separable. I still have to think about the other conditions... (or do you have a solution, meanwhile?)